# Анимация JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Есть анимация

```js
window.onload = function() {

    // track the mouse positions to send it to the shaders
    var mousePosition = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    };
  
    // pass the id of the div that will wrap the canvas to set up our WebGL context and append the canvas to our wrapper
    var webGLCurtain = new Curtains({
      container: "canvas"
    });
  
    // get our plane element
    var planeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("plane")[0];
  
  
    // set our initial parameters (basic uniforms)
    var params = {
      vertexShaderID: "plane-vs", // our vertex shader ID
      fragmentShaderID: "plane-fs", // our framgent shader ID
      widthSegments: 20,
      heightSegments: 20, // we now have 20*20*6 = 2400 vertices !
      uniforms: {
        time: {
          name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
          type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
          value: 0,
        },
        mousePosition: { // our mouse position
          name: "uMousePosition",
          type: "2f", // notice this is a length 2 array of floats
          value: [mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y],
        },
        mouseStrength: { // the strength of the effect (we will attenuate it if the mouse stops moving)
          name: "uMouseStrength", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
          type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
          value: 0,
        },
      }
    }
  
    // create our plane mesh
    var plane = webGLCurtain.addPlane(planeElement, params);
  
    // if our plane has been successfully created we could start listening to mouse/touch events and update its uniforms
    plane && plane.onReady(function() {
      // set a field of view of 35 to exagerate perspective
      // we could have done  it directly in the initial params
      plane.setPerspective(0);
  
      // listen our mouse/touch events on the whole document
      // we will pass the plane as second argument of our function
      // we could be handling multiple planes that way
      document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        handleMovement(e, plane);
      });
  
      document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
        handleMovement(e, plane);
      });
  
    }).onRender(function() {
      // update our time uniform value
      plane.uniforms.time.value++;
  
      // continually decrease mouse strength
      plane.uniforms.mouseStrength.value = Math.max(0.1, plane.uniforms.mouseStrength.value - .7075);
    });
  
  
    // handle the mouse move event
    function handleMovement(e, plane) {
  
      // touch event
      if(e.targetTouches) {
        mousePosition.x = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
        mousePosition.y = e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
      }
      // mouse event
      else {
        mousePosition.x = e.clientX;
        mousePosition.y = e.clientY;
      }
  
      // convert our mouse/touch position to coordinates relative to the vertices of the plane
      var mouseCoords = plane.mouseToPlaneCoords(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
      // update our mouse position uniform
      plane.uniforms.mousePosition.value = [mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y];
  
      // reassign mouse strength
      plane.uniforms.mouseStrength.value = 1;
    }
  
  }
```

```css
  #canvas {
    /* make the canvas wrapper fits the window */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .plane {
    /* define the size of your plane */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .plane img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; 
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Sporting Grotesque_Bold", sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
    min-width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* hide scrollbars */
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
      <div id="canvas" ></div>
  
      <!-- div used to create our plane -->
      <div class="plane">
        <!-- image that will be used as a texture by our plane -->
        <img src="https://www.martin-laxenaire.fr/csstricks/images/second-example-texture.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      </div>
  
     <script id="plane-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision mediump float;
        #endif
  
        // those are the mandatory attributes that the lib sets
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
  
        // those are mandatory uniforms that the lib sets and that contain our model view and projection matrix
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
            
        // our texture matrix uniform (this is the lib default name, but it could be changed)
        uniform mat4 uTextureMatrix0;
  
        // our time uniform
        uniform float uTime;
  
        // our mouse position uniform
        uniform vec2 uMousePosition;
  
        // our mouse strength
        uniform float uMouseStrength;
  
        // if you want to pass your vertex and texture coords to the fragment shader
        varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
  
        void main() {
          vec3 vertexPosition = aVertexPosition;
  
          // get the distance between our vertex and the mouse position
          float distanceFromMouse = distance(uMousePosition, vec2(vertexPosition.x, vertexPosition.y));
  
          // this will define how close the ripples will be from each other. The bigger the number, the more ripples you'll get
          float rippleFactor = 6.0;
          // calculate our ripple effect
          float rippleEffect = cos(rippleFactor * (distanceFromMouse - (uTime / 120.0)));
  
          // calculate our distortion effect
          float distortionEffect = rippleEffect * uMouseStrength;
  
          // apply it to our vertex position
          vertexPosition +=  distortionEffect / 30.0;
  
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
  
          // varyings
          // thanks to the texture matrix we will be able to calculate accurate texture coords
          // so that our texture will always fit our plane without being distorted
            vTextureCoord = (uTextureMatrix0 * vec4(aTextureCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
            vVertexPosition = vertexPosition;
        }
          </script>
          <script id="plane-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision mediump float;
        #endif
  
        // get our varyings
        varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
  
        // our texture sampler (this is the lib default name, but it could be changed)
        uniform sampler2D uSampler0;
  
        void main() {
          // get our texture coords
          vec2 textureCoords = vTextureCoord;
  
          // apply our texture
          vec4 finalColor = texture2D(uSampler0, textureCoords);
  
          // fake shadows based on vertex position along Z axis
          finalColor.rgb -= clamp(-vVertexPosition.z, 0.0, 1.0);
          // fake lights based on vertex position along Z axis
          finalColor.rgb += clamp(vVertexPosition.z, 0.0, 1.0);
  
          // handling premultiplied alpha (useful if we were using a png with transparency)
          finalColor = vec4(finalColor.rgb * finalColor.a, finalColor.a);
  
          gl_FragColor = finalColor;
        }
          </script>
          <script src="script.js"></script>
          <script src="https://www.curtainsjs.com/build/curtains.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы боковые и верхняя, нижняя сторона не двигались? Пример - https://unitk.ai/ Может как-то скрыть при увеличении или есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.plane {
    /* define the size of your plane */
    width: 120%;
    height: 120vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10vh;
    left: -10vh;
  }
```

Костылек конечно, но идея в том чтобы расширить картинку за видимость страницы и разместить +- в центре. На верный ответ не претендую, так чисто идея.

Comment: я очень долго пыталась это сделать... спасибо вам)